# Twitter Bootstrap - well background colour fades out

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fade

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap to build my web site, but have a problem with the `well` class. The grey background colour that comes with `div class="well"` fades out, and becomes white after a couple of seconds.

anyone have a clue to prevent this?

Comment: Could you maybe add some code to allow someone else to reproduce the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: You must have some jQuery in place doing that. It's not a feature of Bootstrap, and you'll have to give us something more to work with.